# Flux through a cylinder

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, partial-derivative

> Calculate the flow of the vector field $F(x, y, z) = (x, y, z)$ out
> (away from the z-axis) through the cylinder surface $x^2 + y^2 = 4$,
> when $0 ≤ z ≤ 1$, by stop at the surface and use the divergence
> theorem.

The divergence is 3. And then I changed the coordinates to polar where $x=r\cos(\theta), y=r\sin(\theta), z=z$. The bounds are $0 \leq r \leq 2$ and $ 0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$ and $0 \leq z \leq 1$ And the area element is  r so I get $\iiint_{V}3r \ d\theta dr dz = 12\pi$. But the answer is $8\pi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The surface of the cylinder consists of three parts:
\begin{align}
S_{\text{top}} = \{ (x, y, z) \in \mathbb R^3 : x^2 + y^2 < 4, z = 1 \}, \\
S_{\text{bottom}} = \{ (x, y, z) \in \mathbb R^3 : x^2 + y^2 < 4, z = 0 \}, \\
S_{\text{curved}} = \{ (x, y, z) \in \mathbb R^3 : x^2 + y^2 = 4, 0 \leq z \leq 1 \} .
\end{align}

The question is asking you to compute
$$ \iint_{S_{\text{curved}}} \mathbf F . d\mathbf A.$$

However, you have computed
$$ \iiint_{V} \mathbf \nabla .\mathbf F \ dV,$$
which is equal to
$$ \iint_{S_{\text{top}}} \mathbf F . d\mathbf A + \iint_{S_{\text{bottom}}} \mathbf F . d\mathbf A + \iint_{S_{\text{curved}}} \mathbf F . d\mathbf A.$$

So you probably want to compute $\iint_{S_{\text{top}}} \mathbf F . d\mathbf A$ and $\iint_{S_{\text{bottom}}} \mathbf F . d\mathbf A $, and subtract these from your answer for $ \iiint_{V} \mathbf \nabla .\mathbf F \ dV$.

You should find that
$$ \iint_{S_{\text{top}}} \mathbf F . d\mathbf A = \iint_{x^2 + y^2 < 4 } 1 \ dx dy = 4\pi$$
and
$$ \iint_{S_{\text{top}}} \mathbf F . d\mathbf A = \iint_{x^2 + y^2 < 4} 0 \ dxdy = 0.$$

I hope you can fill in the details.

Comment: Aha so they are just interested in the mantle surface of the cylinder? If I understand you correctly then I was I supposed to understand that given the context of this question?

Comment: The clue is the phrase "away from the $z$ axis". The integrals on the top and bottom surfaces would be "along the $z$ axis".

Comment: One more question why is z affecting our area at the top and bottom?

Comment: On the top surface, $F = (x,y,1)$. On the bottom surface, $F = (x,y,0)$.